# Error when installing Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

When I install Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10, the following error appears:

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.ParameterBuilder
>   System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder.DefineParameter(Int32,
>   System.Reflection.ParameterAttributes, System.String)'..

[image]

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What is the express installer package size ? I see your picture the selected file size is 74.1 KB

Comment: I install the **SQLEXPR_x64_ENU** package that size is 201 MB and SETUP size is 74.1 KB.

Comment: Please help me i confused.

Comment: I am try down SQL Server 2014 Express package, According office document and I download the image.I think the size is 196.7 MB.
Do you have try re-download the image?
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299